# How to print custom-fields into a log file from java application with the help of log4j2 JSON technique?

Tags: java, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I am looking for to print-out a log in a custom manner.

***For example,***

currently we have following log structure in form of JSON,

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1488791217953,
  "thread" : "restartedMain",
  "level" : "DEBUG",
  "loggerName" : "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource",
  "message" : "hello world",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog",
  "threadId" : 17,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

Now I found that, there were couple of fields are still missing which are important for me to have in a log,

***Expected JSON would be likewise :***

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1488791217953,
  "thread" : "restartedMain",
  "level" : "DEBUG",
  .................. 
  "file" : "p1.pck.HelloWorld.java",
  "line" : "190",
  "application-id" : "101",
  "logged in user id " : "199",
  "etc" : "etc"
  ..................
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

**NOTE :** the log configuration file `log4j2.yml` has following configuration

```
JsonLayout:
          propertiesAsList: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to include the log4j-web artifact to get context data in your log -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, you may find an artifact I created useful [extended-jsonlayout]. It allows you to add additional information to the json log message by implementing a simple interface, and including the jar on your classpath. You can check it out here -
https://github.com/savantly-net/log4j2-extended-jsonlayout